# Octal to decimal conversion using %i

Tags: c

```
int main() { int i; scanf("%i",&i); printf("%d",i); }
```

If i am taking `i/p` as -077 , i am getting -63 as expected, but if `i/p` is -078 then `o/p` is -7.

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What would you expect it to do for an invalid digit?

Answer (score 2):

> but if i/p is -078 then o/p is -7. Can you please explain ???

The conversion stops at the first character that is not a valid digit in the used base. Since the number starts with a `'0'`, not directly followed by an `'x'` or `'X'`, the chosen base is 8. `'8'` is not an octal digit. Therefore the conversion consumes only `"07"`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because 8 is not a valid digit in octal notation.
  Use 0-7.